# why are my zip files not being output from code using python?

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup, download

I am looking to scrape all the files from this webpage, which are zip files: http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

DOMAIN = "insert here"
URL = "insert here"

def get_soup(URL):
 return bs(requests.get(URL).text, 'html.parser')


for link in get_soup(URL).findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile(".zip")}):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    print(file_link)

with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
response = requests.get(DOMAIN + file_link)
file.write(response.content)
```

The code seems to create a file, however the contents of the file are empty. I can see in the python running output all of the zip files, but they are not within the file. Can someone help me find out how I can get these files into my computer? I am so stuck here!

Thank you so much, Lily

Answer (score -1, accepted):

could You check if:

```
for link in get_soup(URL).findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile(".zip")}):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    print(file_link)

with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
response = requests.get(DOMAIN + file_link)
file.write(response.content)
```

would be fixed with that?

```
for link in get_soup(URL).findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile(".zip")}):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    print(file_link)

    with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
        response = requests.get(DOMAIN + file_link)
        file.write(response.content)
```

As the Python is really explicit about ident it could hurt (Your code was not running inside the for-loop but after that).

I suggest using some GUI debugger next time (see, how easy to set in VScode or other IDE GUI) or using ipython with ipdb (`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`)

It is not complete answer, as You should get easily over it if You use debugger and work with Your code. Appreciate Your futher work to learn and persistance :)

Comment: thank you ever so much for your help, I have corrected the issue and it has now downloaded all my files!

Comment: Great to hear @Lily !

Please work on the debugging the prior problem with ipdb python package to see what it actually had in variables, and learn that way. It would help You on your future problems.

Dont hesitate to mark me on futher problems right away (idk if it possible, but believe it is).

If You solved the problem with my help, would apprieciate mark question as answered. This would build my credibility and allow me to help futher with more questions, better. Thanks :)

Comment: I will definitely do that, thank you! I am so thankful you could help me today and I have upvoted you. I always like learning something new and am glad to be on here and thankful for the support :)

Comment: Thanks @Lily 
no problem keep good work! :) the other answer is also great but I believe it would be hard for You to understand async python as You need to work on some pythonista basics.

Working with ipython would really help You and ipdb would be also great to work with as it allow You to debug your scripts rapidly :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import httpx
import trio

mainurl = "http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html"


async def downloader(rec):
    async with rec:
        async for client, link in rec:
            print(f'[*] Downloading --> {link}')
            async with await trio.open_file(link.split('/')[-1], 'wb') as f:
                r = await client.get(link)
                await f.write(r.content)


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        r = await client.get(mainurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        links = [mainurl[:36] + x['href'] for x in soup.select('a[href$=zip]')]

        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)

        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(3):
                nurse.start_soon(downloader, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for link in links:
                    await sender.send([client, link])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Comment: Thank you  αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη , that is also so helpful! I will go through that and have a look in addition. Really appreciate your support!